# To install Blockdev in OSX?

Tags: homebrew, install

I did not find the command in Brew of Yosemite 10.10.3. 
I am reading the command developed from [here](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/6177/dd-with-progress-bar-and-statistics):

```
pv -s $(blockdev –getsize64 /Users/masi/Dropbox/1/r3.raw)
```

I think `blockdev` is Linux specific command at the moment and not existing directly in OSX.

How can you install Blockdev in OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the size of a mounted block device (which is what `blockdev -getsize64` does), you can use the following:

```
diskutil information <device> | grep "Total Size" | sed -e 's/[^(]*(([^Bytes)]*\).*/\1/'
```

If you want to do the same for a file, you can use the following (amongst many others):

```
stat -f '%z' <filename>
```